# What is the variation of pressure in rotating fluids(in accordance to the question in the image)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, calculus

This is an interesting question that I came across. Please see attachment.[image]

It is a multiple answer type question. My answer was B and D. I have attached my derivation for this problem. I want to know if this problem can be solved by assuming this situation to be that of a 'free vortex flow' of the fluid. I have no idea about vortex flow, hence I would be kindly obliged if an answer solving this question by my requested method is given.[image]

Comment: Why did you choose answers B and D?

Comment: Well I took the equation: dp/dx= -ρa, where dx is the differential element on the horizontal axis at a distance x from the vertical. Then since this is filled with air I took the density of air to be, ρ=PM/RT, as the question permits me to assume air to be an ideal gas. Later 'a' is the centripetal force which the element would experience, a=-ω²x. Hence alas I got: ∫dp=(Mω²/RT)∫xdx. I integrated pressure from Pc to Pa, and element from 0 to L. Now I thought since A is open to the atmosphere, Pa=Po, hence my expression boils down to: lnPc/Po =-ML²ω²/2RT, so Pc= Po*exponential(-βω²L²) ,β=M/2RT.

Comment: And since points C and D are along the same vertical line the pressures must be approx. the same. More over Pc<Pb<Pa(=Po), so Pd+ρgh=Po, hence Pd=Pc= Po-hρg. In all of this my assumption was hydrostatic equilibrium, but I am not sure if the liquid in the vertical arm continues to rise, if it does then the analysis would become nasty due to consideration of variation of elemental parts with cross section. This is the reason why I have asked if this question can be solved using the concept of 'free vortex flow'(as I was informed), but I have no idea about this vortex stuff.

Comment: I am sorry your question has been put on hold, Naveen.  I think you are correct to assume that hydrostatic equilibrium has been reached.  I expected that Bernoulli's Equation would have to be applied at A.  You have obtained a value for beta.  So does this solve your problem?  If not, update your question (you could cut and paste your derivation into it) to state what help you still require, then contact a Moderator to ask if the question can be taken off hold.

Comment: Sammy gerbil, I have edited my question and have attached my derivation. What I really seek is an alternate method to solve this problem, or problems like these in general. I was informed that assuming vortex flows help in simplifying situations like these, hence all I need is to know that method so I can make a gross generalisation. And yes, I did try the Bernoulli method but that proves to be tiresome.